# Boot timeout when deploying an sbt project to heroku

Tags: scala, heroku, deployment, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I have a microservice written in Scala that primarily runs scheduled jobs. It's not a play app. The main function just sets up the scheduled jobs. For example

```
import cronish.dsl._

object workers {
  def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = {
    val payroll: CronTask = task {
      println("Syncing Payroll...")
    }
    payroll executes "every 5 minutes"

  }
}
```

I deployed this to Heroku and while the job begins to run as expected, Heroku kills it every single time after 60 seconds.

```
Syncing Payroll...
Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
Stopping process with SIGKILL
Process exited with status 137
State changed from starting to crashed
```

I've followed the [official Heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-scala). Here is what my build.sbt looks like

```
name := "AppName"
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.11.9"
enablePlugins(JavaServerAppPackaging)

libraryDependencies += "com.smartsheet" % "smartsheet-sdk-java" % "2.2.2"
libraryDependencies += "com.github.philcali" %% "cronish" % "0.1.3"
libraryDependencies +=  "org.scalaj" %% "scalaj-http" % "2.3.0"
....
```

and I've added both of the Heroku plugins to the plugins.sbt file as well

```
addSbtPlugin("com.heroku" % "sbt-heroku" % "2.0.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.3.1")
```

It runs totally fine on development if I use sbt run. I'm thinking that Heroku is expecting this service to be a web server so it keeps trying to attach it to an open port however since this service is not a web-server it can't do that. Is it possible to deploy such microservices to Heroku? Do it need to use a custom build pack?

Comment: Are you aware of heroku's concept of web- vs worker dynos? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/background-jobs-queueing

Comment: Just read the article. Seems like I need to specify the worker in the Procfile. It tells the command for java application is java -jar path/to/jar but not for scala applications.

Comment: I tried putting `worker: target/universal/stage/bin/{myAppName}` in the Procfile but seems like my the process is not running

Comment: Run `heroku ps:scale worker=1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Procfile` should use `worker:` instead of `web:`. For example:

```
worker: target/universal/stage/bin/{myAppName}
```

Then scale up the "worker" dynos by running:

```
$ heroku ps:scale worker=1
```

You can name the process anything you want (doesn't have to be "worker"), but "web" dynos are treated specially. Heroku expects them to bind to a port and serve web requests.